# Not able see the `tree` structure with required depth

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I am using windows 10, in the `powershell` I would like to see the folder `tree` structure with required depth level. for that I use the following command:

```
 tree -F -L 1
```

But I came up with following:

```
PS E:\Tutorials> tree -F -L 1
Too many parameters - -L
```

What is wrong here? and  what is the correct way to see the `tree` structure in `windows`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you get the command `tree -F -L 1` from?

Comment: I red in a book

Comment: A Powershell book?

Comment: No, it is NG-2 book ( angular 2 ) if the command is wrong, I would like to know the exact command what I should use in windows

Comment: Well that is not possible unless you tell us what the parameters `-F`, `-L` and `1` are supposed to do.

Comment: I would like to see the folder structure in the powershell for that if I run `Tree` it show all depth. But i required to limit the depth like Depth-1 or some way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60505/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-davidpostill).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### How do I show a directory tree in Powershell with a specified depth?

You can use the `Show-Tree` cmdlet from the [PowerShell Community Extension Project](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Pscx/3.2.2).

**To install `show-tree`:**

```
> Install-Script -Name Show-Tree

Untrusted repository
You are installing the scripts from an untrusted repository. If you trust this repository, change its InstallationPolicy value by running the Set-PSRepository cmdlet. Are you sure you want to install
 the scripts from 'PSGallery'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): a
```

**To get help on `show-tree`:**

```
> get-help show-tree

NAME
    Show-Tree

SYNOPSIS
    Shows the specified path as a tree.


SYNTAX
    Show-Tree [[-Path] <String[]>] [[-Depth] <Int32>] [-Force] [-IndentSize <Int32>] [-ShowLeaf] [-ShowProperty] [-ExcludeProperty <String[]>] [-Width <Int32>] [-UseAsciiLineArt] [<CommonParameters>]

    Show-Tree [[-LiteralPath] <String[]>] [[-Depth] <Int32>] [-Force] [-IndentSize <Int32>] [-ShowLeaf] [-ShowProperty] [-ExcludeProperty <String[]>] [-Width <Int32>] [-UseAsciiLineArt]
    [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    Shows the specified path as a tree.  This works for any type of PowerShell provider and can be used to explore providers used for configuration like the WSMan provider.


RELATED LINKS

REMARKS
    To see the examples, type: "get-help Show-Tree -examples".
    For more information, type: "get-help Show-Tree -detailed".
    For technical information, type: "get-help Show-Tree -full".
```

**Example output:**

```
> Show-Tree f:\test –depth 2
F:\test
├──subdir
│  └──child
├──test
├──test with space
│  └──child
└──test.with.dot
   └──child
>
```

Comment: I have thrown an error as :

Comment: `PS C:\xampp\htdocs\angular-hello-world> Install-Script -Name Show-Tree
Install-Script : The term 'Install-Script' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Script -Name Show-Tree
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-Script:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: Install the handlers... `Install-Module -Name Pscx`

Comment: I have installed  `Pscx` as per you said. still it show the same error. Is this require to restart my system or anything else?

Comment: @3gwebtrain No, a restart should not be required. Did you install as an Administrator?

Comment: Yes, I installed as admin only. and the installation was success. How can i check `Pscx` status on my system?

Comment: -MaxDepth instesd of -Depth
`SYNTAX
    C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts\Show-Tree.ps1 [[-Path] <Object>] [-MaxDepth <Int32>] [-ShowDirectory]
    [-NotLike <String[]>] [-Like <String[]>] [<CommonParameters>]`

Comment: @MalusJan There are actually two kinds of `show-tree`, see [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1756146/478169).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much [DavidPostill♦](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill) for [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/1219509/478169).

But There is a catch in this.

There are two kinds of `Show-Tree`, one is a script of PowerShell and the other is a function of Pscx.

- [[PowerShell Script] Show-Tree](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Show-Tree/1.0.0)

  - Install

    ```sh
    Install-Script -Name Show-Tree
    ```
  - Syntax

    ```sh
    Show-Tree [[-Path] <Object>] [-MaxDepth <Int32>] [-ShowDirectory] [-NotLike <String[]>] [-Like <String[]>] [<CommonParameters>]
    ```
- [[Pscx](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Pscx/3.3.2) Function] Show-Tree

  - Install

    ```sh
    Install-Module -Name Pscx -AllowClobber
    ```
  - Syntax

    ```sh
    Show-Tree [[-Path] <String[]>] [[-Depth] <Int32>] [-Force] [-IndentSize <Int32>] [-ShowLeaf] [-ShowProperty] [-ExcludeProperty <String[]>] [-Width <Int32>] [-UseAsciiLineArt] [<CommonParameters>]

    Show-Tree [[-LiteralPath] <String[]>] [[-Depth] <Int32>] [-Force] [-IndentSize <Int32>] [-ShowLeaf] [-ShowProperty] [-ExcludeProperty <String[]>] [-Width <Int32>] [-UseAsciiLineArt] [<CommonParameters>]
    ```

Pscx's `Show-Tree` is more powerful and supports showing the leaf items in each container.

Examples are as follows:

```shell
PS> show-tree C:\Users\jqgsninimo\tree\ -depth 3 -showleaf
C:\Users\jqgsninimo\tree\
├──1
│  ├──2
│  │  ├──3
│  │  └──3.txt
│  └──2.txt
└──1.txt
```

If `[PS Script] Show-Tree` is installed by mistake, you can execute the following commands to replace it.

```shell
PS> uninstall-script -name show-tree
PS> Install-Module -Name Pscx -AllowClobber
```